# SQL Alchemy with PG8000 exception in IN query: invalid input syntax for type integer: "{2,3,5,6,7}"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pg8000

```
cursor.execute(text("SELECT * FROM pnl WHERE type IN (:types)"))
```

Works.

The Following tests:

```
cursor.execute(text("SELECT * FROM pnl WHERE type IN (:types)"), types=[2, 3, 5, 6, 7])
cursor.execute(text("SELECT * FROM pnl WHERE type IN (:types)"), types=tuple([2, 3, 5, 6, 7]))
cursor.execute(text("SELECT * FROM pnl WHERE type IN (:types)"), types=list([2, 3, 5, 6, 7]))
```

Throws exception:

```
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405) - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Git/argus-periodic/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pg8000/legacy.py", line 252, in execute
    self._context = self._c.execute_unnamed(
  File "/Git/argus-periodic/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 649, in execute_unnamed
    self.handle_messages(context)
  File "/Git/argus-periodic/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 767, in handle_messages
    raise self.error
pg8000.exceptions.DatabaseError: {'S': 'ERROR', 'V': 'ERROR', 'C': '22P02', 'M': 'invalid input syntax for type integer: "{2,3,5,6,7}"', 'F': 'numutils.c', 'L': '323', 'R': 'pg_strtoint32'}
```

So how can I pass a list to use in the IN query for sql alchemy.

Comment: remove the parentheses around `(:types)` in your query

Comment: [SQL: SELECT * FROM pnl WHERE type IN %s]
[parameters: ((2, 3, 5, 6, 7),)]
...
pg8000.exceptions.DatabaseError: {'S': 'ERROR', 'V': 'ERROR', 'C': '42601', 'M': 'syntax error at or near "$1"', 'P': '33', 'F': 'scan.l', 'L': '1180', 'R': 'scanner_yyerror'

Looks like it comes a trailing empty parameter?

Answer (score 1):

There are idiosyncrasies in both pg8000's and SQLAlchemy's handling of `IN` clauses that need to be considered here.

pg8000 [requires](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#in-and-not-in) parameterised `IN` queries to take this form

```sql
SELECT col FROM tbl WHERE col IN (SELECT(unnest(CAST(:params) AS integer[])))
```

So the code would look like this:

```py
values = {'types': [1, 2, 5]}
q = sa.text('select id from users where id in (select(unnest(cast(:types as integer[]))))')

with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(q, values)
    # Do stuff with result
```

SQLAlchemy on the other hand, requires that we mark parameters as [expanding](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam.params.expanding) when used as the target of an `IN` clause.

So the final SQLAlchemy code, would look like this (which I think is more idiomatic):

```py
values = {'types': [2, 3, 5, 6, 7]}
q = sa.text('select * from pnl where type in :types')
q = q.bindparams(sa.bindparam('types', expanding=True))

with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(q, values)
    # Do stuff with result.
```

The difference between the two statements is caused by the way the parameters are passed. The "native" pg8000 statement is passed a row object `((1, 2, 5),)` which must be unnested etc. The SQLAlchemy version receives individual values:  `(1, 2, 5)`.

Answer (score 1):

Further to @snakecharmerb 's answer, you can also avoid having to remember the idiosyncrasies of each driver (e.g., pg8000) by letting SQLAlchemy build the SELECT statement for you:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# …

pnl = sa.Table("pnl", sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

engine.echo = True
with engine.begin() as conn:
    types = [2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
    stmt = (
        sa.select(sa.text("*")).select_from(pnl).where(pnl.c.type.in_(types))
    )
    results = conn.execute(stmt).all()

"""SQL emitted:
SELECT * 
FROM pnl 
WHERE pnl.type IN (%s::INTEGER, %s::INTEGER, %s::INTEGER, %s::INTEGER, %s::INTEGER)
[generated in 0.00042s] (2, 3, 5, 6, 7)
"""
```